# Passing Control from one Event to another in C#

Tags: c#, event-handling, infragistics, ultrawingrid

Following are the details of my problem:

I have 2 user controls (U1 and U2) in a Workspace. My first User Control U1 contains a grid. U2 has a richtextbox control in it. Currently when we change some data in a row in U1, and click the save button, the data is entered in database. When a child row is created for a row in U1 grid, it has U2 embedded in it. When i enter data in the richtextbox and click on Save. Save does not fire properly.

Purpose:

I need to save the data entered in textbox in a variable before the Save event is fired. 
So, am using the leave event of textbox to save the text.

Problem:

But when i enter some data in the textbox and click on save, first the Leave event of textbox is fired and so the Save function does not fire properly.

Could anyone provide any hint as to what event of textbox i can use to do the following without affecting save functionality or any other approach to it?

Comment: Could you post the code on the leave event and the click event?

Comment: And looking at the first answer, are we talking about UltraWebGrid or UtraWinGrid?

Comment: What is meant by Save does not fire properly?  What triggers the save?  Is this a button, toolbar, menu?  What platform is this?  It is mentioned that the second user control is used within the grid.  If this is the WinGrid using a ControlContainerEditor and the save is triggered by a toolbar or menu then it is possible that the data hasn't been persisted for the row that is currently being edited since the toolbar or menu wouldn't take focus.  If this is the case you should use test calling UltraGrid.PerformAction(UltraGridAction.CommitRow) in your save logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using server side lost focus (leave) event of textbox , then after postback this event will be fired.

So you had to wait for postback to complete beore clicking on save button.

If you have to store the value of textbox , you can create a hidden field and use textbox's client side blur event to store value at clientside only.

e.g.

javascript:

function savedata()
{
hdnValue.value = document.getElementById('TextBox1').value ;
}

Later after postback you can use this value from hidden field before performing Save operation.